# Data Collection App Widget

Tags: android, data

I'm looking for an Android app that allows me to quickly collect data via widgets into a standard format such as sqlite or csv. The data should be stored somewhere so it can be automatically (without user intervention) synced by [syncthing-fork](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.catfriend1.syncthingandroid&hl=en_US&gl=US) or [perkeep](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.camlistore) on Android 11. At the moment I'm only interested in logging times though in the future I might be interested in text annotations or state transitions (multiple-choice).

I have a script at the synchronization target/computer that uses [vega-lite](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/) to visualize the data.

I prefer the app also have a UI to edit the data in case I make any mistakes during data entry.

Geo- or WiFi- fencing to remind you to collect data would be a plus but is not required as server-side analysis should substitute.

Comment: "Data" is quite an abstract term – unless you specify exactly what kind of data you want to collect, and how (entering manually? automatically? single data points like "scalars", or relations like "arrays"/"records"?) I don't think there's an "universal solution for all kind of data", ready to use by everyone without any programming knowledge. You could eg use automation tools like Tasker to create something like that – but that will be some work.

Comment: I want to use an app widget (the type that can be placed on the home screen) to enter the data. I really like the way [Track and Graph](https://github.com/SamAmco/track-and-graph) works but unfortunately export only happens manually. Like I said, the only data I'm interested in *right now* is times, in any standard format like sqlite or csv. So a simply button should suffice.